# Android Storage Access Framework: Accessing an unexported content provider from DocumentsProvider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

My Storage Access Framework DocumentsProvider is using the existing content provider in my app to access a database table that stores information on files from my server that I have stored locally on the device. This works fine when I access the content provider from openDocument. However, when I access it from createDocument I get an SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing ... uri ... requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission(). This occurs when using QuickOffice to create a new file in my documents provider. My database content provider isn't exported because it's for internal use in the app only. Given that both providers are in my app, why do I need permission to access by database content provider? Is there any workaround short of exporting my database content provider.

Answer (score 0):

It's enforcing security on your internal ContentProvider based on the Binder identity of the incoming caller.  The incoming caller has a Uri permission grant to get into your `DocumentsProvider`, but when you turn around and access your second internal provider, it denies access based on their identity, as it should.

If you know for sure that the caller should have access, you can temporarily release their identity, and revert to the normal identity of your app, allowing you to access your internal provider.

Here's an example:

```
    // Delegate to real provider
    final long token = Binder.clearCallingIdentity();
    try {
        return getContext().getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(target, mode);
    } finally {
        Binder.restoreCallingIdentity(token);
    }
```